# Unable to deselect items in migration-assistant

Tags: macos, migration-assistant

I had created a test user upon installing Mountain Lion, now I want to import my regular user from backup, but only that particular user and no other users nor applications. However in the Migration-Assistent window all check boxes are greyed out for my most recent backup (both for my carbon copy clone and the TimeMachine backup) even though I could change the selection for a much older backup. What can be done to allow me to make a selection instead of needing to import everything ?

Comment: Same issue I'm having. The select file step in Migration Assistant is all greyed out and this can select specific files. I wonder if the latest back up is deleted, perhaps the previous backup can work?

Answer (score 1):

This posting seems to suggest it might be something to do with Server.app software - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4157337?tstart=0

On the new machine, you might try removing Server.app from the /Applications folder and restarting. It might be that you need to remove Server.app from the backup before doing the migration - perhaps you can boot from the clone and remove it from the clone. Removing Server.app from the /Applications folder should cause the system to warn you that it will shut down all the server services, but should otherwise leave the server data and settings intact so when Server.app is reinstalled everything will be as it was before.

Server.app seems to also cause probelms with "not enough room" warnings that are incorrect but still prevent Migration Assistant.app from completing its job as detailed in [Migrate OS X using Migration Assistant and Time Machine - not enough space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164315/migrate-os-x-using-migration-assistant-and-time-machine-not-enough-space/250110#250110)